# Shadowbox loads old href and not new href

Tags: jquery, load, lightbox, href, shadowbox

I have a code that replaces href's using Jquery, .attr({ href : newpath }); and I am using Shadowbox. After changing the href and loading shadowbox, the shadowbox loads the old href instead of the new one.

For example :

`<a id ="shadowboxlink" href="images/firstimage.jpg" rel="shadowbox">shadowbox link</a>`

then the jquery would be something like this :

`$("#shadowboxlink").attr({href : newpath}); 
//whereas var newpath is a string like "images/secondimage.jpg"`

so then after jquery is executed, the shadowbowlink has the correct href of images/secondimage.jpg, but when you load it, the shadowbox loads the firstimage.jpg

Anyone have any insight? Thanks! =)
Ken

Answer (score 4):

try clearing cache and setup after change the href attribute

```
$("#shadowboxlink").attr({href : newpath}); //whereas var newpath is a string like "images/secondimage.jpg";
Shadowbox.clearCache();
Shadowbox.setup();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - @ken, you should really mark this as correct so can get the kudos he deserves :)

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at the information provided on the shadowBox website, it sounds like what you want to do is just add a second `<a>` in your markup.

```
<a id ="shadowboxlink" href="images/firstimage.jpg" rel="shadowbox[gallery]">shadowbox link</a>
<a id ="shadowboxlink" href="images/second.jpg" rel="shadowbox[gallery]">shadowbox link</a>
```

And make sure you add the [gallery] (or whatever you want to call it) to associate those two images with each other.

If that's not what you're looking to do, try running the `Shadowbox.init();` code again after changing the href.

Comment: sorry, i don't really understand what you meant by "adding a second <a> in my markup"

the shadowbox.init() didnt' work =/ , the shadowbox is still loading the first href and not the second href

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use "Shadowbox.setup" and reload it whenever you click something.

Thanks everyone.